# jQuery FullCalendar. Default to first month with event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the below code to initialise a jQuery FullCalendar.

However, not all months have any events. I would like the initial month view of the calendar to be the first month with an event.

So as an example. It is currently June, there are no events in the Calendar until August so I would like would like the initial view of the calendar to default to August rather than June.

Likewise, if there ARE events in June, I would like it to default to June.

```
$('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar({
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            header: {
                left: 'prev',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'next'
            },
            events: function(start, end, callback) {

                $.getJSON(jSONCalendarURL, {
                            token:jSONAPItoken,
                            productID: $('#fullCalendar').attr("data-id"),
                            startDate: $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
                            endDate: $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
                        }, function(data){
                        var calevents = [];
                        $.each(data.response, function(index,item){
                            calDate = index;
                            child = item.Variations;
                            if (child.length > 0 ){
                                if (!$.isEmptyObject(child)){
                                    calPrice = child[0].Price;
                                    calID = child[0].ID;
                                    calAvailable = child[0].Available;
                                    calevents.push({
                                        'id': calID,
                                        'title': buildEventTitle(calAvailable,calDate.substring(calDate.length,calDate.length-2),child[0].Price, calID, child[0].RRP),
                                        'start': $.fullCalendar.parseDate(calDate),
                                        'end': $.fullCalendar.parseDate(calDate),
                                        'allDay': true
                                    });

                                }
                            }
                        });
                        callback(calevents);
                        highlightExisting();

                    }
                );
            },

            eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
                if (event.start.getMonth() != view.start.getMonth())
                    return false;
            },
            weekMode:'liquid'
        });
```

Is what I am trying to do achievable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely achievable! You will need to first start with sorting your events array and finding the next registered event object. Then you can use the .fullCalendar('gotoDate') method to jump to that date.

Something like this:

```
function custom_sort(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.start).getTime() - new Date(b.start).getTime();
}

events_array.sort(custom_sort);

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', events_array[0].start);
```

Please refer this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/YhEBx/) for a working static example.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh, and do check if the next date is greater than today (or previous month) - to make sure that you don't go backwards.

Comment: how to achieve this if the events are fetched by url and not placed into an array?